# How to understand logging dead letter akka

Tags: scala, akka

I am getting dead letter actor in logs. And the logging is of level INFO. But I am not getting which method from sActor is giving dead letter. Following is the log message

```
 akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef - Message [scala.util.Right] from Actor[akka://marksun-app/user/marksun-api/sActor/$a#-396914220] to Actor[akka://marksun-app/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I want to know what is `

> $a#-396914220

`

Comment: From the Akka doc: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/addressing.html#what-is-an-actor-path-

Answer (score 0):

The `$a#-396914220` is the actor's name (`$a`) and the actor was spawned as a child of an actor named `sActor`.  The `396914220` is the unique ID of the cell in which the actor runs.

No stacktrace or other information is captured when sending a message, so it's not possible to know from where in `sActor` the message is being sent.

If you're not explicitly spawning an actor in `sActor` to send a message, the two most likely culprits are using the "ask" pattern (which will spawn a temporary actor) or possibly running a stream (which will spawn actors to materialize the stream).

Comment: sorry, this could be a stupid question. meaning of explicitly spawning an actor? Means logging in Actor

Comment: spawning is creating a new actor... has nothing to do with logging.

Comment: Basically, an actor which is a child of `sActor` is sending a message to another actor, but that actor is no longer there, thus the message goes to dead letters.

Comment: One last question, will this dead letter impact the queue/pool(thread-pool-executor) of actor (sActor)?

Comment: No, it won't have an impact like that.  It may indicate that a reference to an actor with a limited lifetime is being improperly propagated, the actor you intend to interact with has failed.  It may also (if the actor in question is a remote actor), indicate network problems.  Alternatively, if you're seeing these as the application shuts down, that's to be expected and normal.

Comment: Actually, the application is giving 502 Bad Gateway on the APIs for some time but later it starts working (no restart). The only difference that I can see in logs is a dead letter